# Select não é inicializado com valor padrão

Tags: html5, angular, typescript, formulário

Criei um componente que possui um campo de tipo `<select>` e recebe uma propriedade `[modelo]` como entrada: se o modelo for nulo, o formulário é inicializado vazio; se possuir conteúdo, é inicializado para modificação.

**HTML**:

```
<form [formGroup]="modeloForm" (ngSubmit)="ngSubmit(modeloForm.value)">
  <input type="text" formControlName="name" id="name" placeholder="Nome"/>
  <label for="name">Nome</label>

  <select formControlName="item_id" id="item_id">
    <option [ngValue]="null" disabled selected>Escolha o banco:</option>
    <option *ngFor="let item of itens" [ngValue]="item.id">{{ item.name }}</option>
  </select>
  <button id="submit-btn" type="submit">
    Cadastrar
  </button>
</form>
```

**Typescript**:

```
itens: Item = ITENS; // array de itens importados de classe à parte
modeloForm: FormGroup;
_modelo: Modelo | null = null;

@Input() set modelo(modelo: Modelo | null){
  this._modelo = modelo;

  // tentei setar usando com a sintaxe do JavaScript, mas sem sucesso
  document.getElementById("item_id").nodeValue = !!this._modelo ? this._modelo.item_id + '' : '';

  // função que serve para resetar o formulário
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.modeloForm.reset({
      name: !!this._modelo ? this._modelo.name : '',
      item_id: !!this._modelo ? this._modelo.item_id : ''
    });
  }, 100);
}
```

**Modelos**:

```
interface Modelo{
  id: number;
  name: string;
  item_id: number;
}

interface Item{
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

const ITENS: Item[] = [
  {id:1, name:'item1'},
  {id:2, name:'item2'},
  {id:3, name:'item3'},
  {id:4, name:'item4'},
  {id:5, name:'item5'}
];
```

Porém, apesar de inicializar o formulário com o nome e o objeto corretamente, o item selecionado no campo `<select>` não aparece até que o campo seja selecionado. Como devo proceder?

Já tentei colocar a inicialização no `ngInit()` (mesmo sabendo que não funcionaria porque o `ngInit` só é chamado quando o componente é inicializado pela primeira vez), inverter a ordem entre a definição pelo `nodeValue` e a pelo `modeloForm`, comentar a linha onde tento setar manualmente pelo `nodeValue`, comentar as linhas onde tento setar pelo `modeloForm.reset` e remover esse trecho do `setTimeout`, todas sem sucesso.

Comment: os valores do vetor `itens` são passados no momento da inicialização do componente, assim como os valores de `modelo` são passados através de uma inbound property. Eu apenas dei um `*ngFor` nos elementos desse array, assim como usei os dados de `modelo` para preencher o formulário. 

A minha questão é mais sobre a propriedade `value` do `select`, que, ao definir um valor padrão, permanece visualmente vazia ao inicializar o componente (se eu selecionei o valor **3**, por exemplo, a opção que vai aparecer como vazia quando eu for visualizar o formulário, mesmo que `modelo` esteja definido)

Comment: Não sei se consegui ser claro, mas, basicamente, no componente a propriedade `modelo` está definida corretamente, e quando eu faço a submissão a propriedade `item_id` do objeto `modelo` está definida, mas, quando eu abro o formulário, o campo `<select>` está em branco, como se a propriedade `item.name` fosse igual a uma string vazia (`""`).

Comment: Não vi nada de errado, o ***ngFor** era pra estar funcionando, tentou trocar o `[ngValue]` por `[value]`?

Comment: Tentei. Não deu certo, o valor continua aparecendo apenas quando o campo é selecionado.

Comment: Não sei se o seu **ngSubmit** aí na sua máquina está errado, mas, aqui está faltando o **(**. Faz o seguinte dentro do **`ngOnInit()`** coloca um console.log(itens) pra ver o que mostra.

Comment: ```(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: 1, name: "item1"}
1: {id: 2, name: "item2"}
2: {id: 3, name: "item3"}
3: {id: 4, name: "item4"}
4: {id: 5, name: "item5"}
length: 5
__proto__: Array(0)```

Comment: A única coisa que acho que pode ser aí, é o **setTimeout()** no set do **modelo**, provavelmente deve estar resetando o select, é a única coisa que vejo para o problema.

Comment: Substituí o código da função `set` pela implementação da interface `OnChanges`, que possui uma função (`ngOnChanges`) chamada sempre que uma inbound property é chamada, o que melhorou um pouco a legibilidade, mas não resolveu o problema.

Comment: @ArthurSiqueira não sei se entendi muito bem mas inicialmente seu combo pode vir sem nenhum valor selecionado e isto está funcionando perfeitamente. Se o valor for definido no modelo `item_id` você gostaria de selecionar o item no combo, seria isto?

Comment: @MarceloVismari exatamente isso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arthur, pelo que entendi, quando o campo `item_id` do seu modelo for preenchido significa que um item deve ser selecionado por padrão no seu combo. Se for isto faça o bind do [value] no seu select. Veja um [exemplo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ny4s6c):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  itens = [
    { id: 1, name: 'item1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'item2' },
    { id: 3, name: 'item3' },
    { id: 4, name: 'item4' },
    { id: 5, name: 'item5' }
  ];

  modelo = {
    item_id: 5
  };
}
```

Template:

```
<select [value]="modelo.item_id">
  <option disabled>Escolha o banco:</option>
  <option *ngFor="let item of itens" [value]="item.id">{{ item.name }}</option>
</select>
```

Se o `item_id` estiver preenchido, ao carregar o componente seu combo terá selecionado o item de mesmo id.

Comment: O grande problema é que eu recebo esses dados do componente pai, e quando abro o filho a opção só é selecionada ao clicar sobre o campo `select`

Comment: @ArthurSiqueira veja se é mais ou menos este cenário: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-faaiys

Comment: tá mais pra esse: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gaqb9z

Comment: @ArthurSiqueira modifiquei um pouco seu exemplo, veja se te atende: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9apubp